# Css <tr> difference between firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css

my css is working fine on firefox, but there is some issues with chrome, as you can see, the tr is not complete.

Do you have an idea of how I could debug this ?

Firefox:

[image: mozilla]

Chrome

[image: chrome]

Here is the corresponding html

```
<tbody>
<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="7"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td colspan="3">↓</td>
    <td>- Km</td>
    <td>- min</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 1861454 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="pdvTaille2">
        ITM0013 - INTERMARCHE ESPERE-SUPER-DRIVE <br>
        RD 911 "LES GRANGES" - 46090 - ESPERE
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
      <td colspan="3">↓</td>
      <td>- Km</td>
      <td>- min</td>
      <td></td>
</tr>                                      

<tr>
    <td colspan="9" class="listeEnquetes"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 1848673 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="pdvTaille2">
        ITM0004 - INTERMARCHE VIEUX-VY-SUR-COUESNON-SUPER-DRIVE <br>
        Z.A. LA CROIX COUVERTE - 35490 - VIEUX-VY-SUR-COUESNON
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td colspan="3">↓</td>
    <td>- Km</td>
    <td>- min</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>                                       

<tr>
    <td colspan="9" class="listeEnquetes"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 1848727 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="pdvTaille2">
        ITM0005 - INTERMARCHE BROONS-SUPER-DRIVE <br>
        PA DU CHALET - 22250 - BROONS
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td colspan="3">↓</td>
    <td>- Km</td>
    <td>- min</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="7"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks for your help, I can add some Css if you need it, but may be it's not that usefull to show everything. Hoping you might have an idea, there is some other issues with other navigator but there was existing before so I just want to focus on that one.

PS: This is the generated code in the console, but it's built with twig.

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle.

Comment: Looks like a bug in firefox instead :/ your columns are not equal, you should span 9 columns on every row, some cells are stand alone, chrome is dealing with it correctly, I see firefox is making assumptions here (or may be its a feature), anyway, the colspan must add to 9

Comment: Have you tried using [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) to remove css inconsistencies between browsers?

Comment: Indeed the colspan wasn't equal...I'm going to try be replacing my colspan 3 by colspan 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just didn't mention anything about the empty cells in that row
In the first row u have used `colspan="2"` and `colspan="7"` to represent complete row and in the third row u have just used `<td></td>`
 That is in the first row you have 9 columns and in the third row you have only one col.
i have made some changes according to my convenience but i don't know the same will work for you or not but the main concept is whatever number of `<td>`s u have used in the first row including `colspan` u have to maintain the same number of cols in following rows according to your requirement.

 If this answer is not clear or you didnt understand at any point please ask me i can explain.

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
        <td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>↓</td>
    <td>- Km</td>
    <td>- min</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 1861454 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="pdvTaille2" colspan="4">
        ITM0013 - INTERMARCHE ESPERE-SUPER-DRIVE <br>
        RD 911 "LES GRANGES" - 46090 - ESPERE
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
      <td>↓</td>
      <td>- Km</td>
      <td>- min</td>
      <td></td>
</tr>                                      

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="listeEnquetes"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 1848673 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="pdvTaille2" colspan="4">
        ITM0004 - INTERMARCHE VIEUX-VY-SUR-COUESNON-SUPER-DRIVE <br>
        Z.A. LA CROIX COUVERTE - 35490 - VIEUX-VY-SUR-COUESNON
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>↓</td>
    <td>- Km</td>
    <td>- min</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>                                       

<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="listeEnquetes"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 1848727 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="pdvTaille2" colspan="4">
        ITM0005 - INTERMARCHE BROONS-SUPER-DRIVE <br>
        PA DU CHALET - 22250 - BROONS
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td>↓</td>
    <td>- Km</td>
    <td>- min</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr class="content_6 firstEnquete firstContent" style="display: table-row;">
    <td colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```